# vb script using XMLDOM

Tags: vb.net, vbscript

I am trying to create an Excel Workbook from XML code using Microsoft XMLDOM.  I am very new to this and have tried researching this but most answers are very hard to understand.  Here is a sample of my XML:

```
<scanmasterCollection>
<CustomerData>
    <companyName></companyName>
    <description></description>
</CustomerData>
  <collectionData>
    <ASH collectedFrom="testServer" version="3.03.00" devicename="tigger"> 
    <servercell>
       <object>
           <objectname>Server1</objectname> 
           <objecttype>servercell</objecttype> 
           <objectsn>456</objectsn> 
       </object>
    </servercell>
    <diskgroup>
       <object>
         <objectid>456</objectid> 
         <objectname>\Disk Groups\100</objectname> 
         <objecttype>diskgroup</objecttype>
         <totalstoragespacegb>4000</totalstoragespacegb>
       </object>
     </diskgroup>
  </ASH>
 </collectionData>
</scanmasterCollection>
```

I am using this in a vb script:

```
objSheet.Cells(iY,3).Value = objConfigXml.selectSingleNode
("//collectionData/ASH/collectedFrom").Attributes.getNamedItem("version").Text

objSheet.Cells(iY,4).Value = objConfigXml.selectSingleNode
("//collectionData/diskgroup/object").Attributes.getNamedItem
("totalstoragespacegb").Text

objSheet.Cells(iY,5).Value = objConfigXml.selectSingleNode
("//collectionData/serverCell/object").Attributes.getNamedItem("objectname").Text
```

I am getting numerous errors.  I've tried for hours to change the paths above.

I need the following values to be returned:
3.03.00
4000
Server1

Can you explain in simple terms how to do this?  Similar code is already running with different XML and I am trying to modify it for this XML.

Comment: So how do I get the value of totalstoragespacegb, objectname, and version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All your XPath expressions fail.

- "//collectionData/ASH/collectedFrom" - collectedFrom is no childnode, but an attribute
- "//collectionData/diskgroup/object" - diskgroup is a child of ASH
- "//collectionData/serverCell/object" - the parent of object is called servercell (mark case) and a child of ASH

While ASH has an attribute `version`, neither `totalstoragespacegb` nor `objectname` are attributes.

**To get you started: tested expressions**

```
 WScript.Echo Join(Array( _
      objMSXML.selectSingleNode("//collectionData/ASH").Attributes.getNamedItem("version").text _
    , objMSXML.selectSingleNode("//collectionData/ASH/diskgroup/object/totalstoragespacegb").text _
    , objMSXML.selectSingleNode("//collectionData/ASH/servercell/object/objectname").text _
 ), vbCrLf)
```

output:

```
3.03.00
4000
Server1
```